# Vercel Local Build with CLI tool fails on pages with getstaticprops

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm following the link below to bypass vercel's build process and upload a locally prebuilt nextjs website to vercel using their CLI tool.

https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-locally-built-nextjs

The specific command is

vercel build && vercel deploy --prebuilt

this works on websites with no special nextjs functions getstaticpaths, getstaticprops etc. I'm trying to use it on pages with getstaticprops. The second it detects a page with that function it produces the following error after it's being pushed to vercel.

/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/functions/_next/data/b0Xu8mG1byq-_oHvJ6_xn/your_page_name.json.func

I've checked the local directory and that folder does exist with content but once it's pushed to vercel it doesnt detect it. Everything works fine locally. I've tried even introducing a getstaticprops function with a hardcoded empty {} object and no external server calls and it still fails

Does anybody know what's the issue?